# Show and hide hidden div with parent onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to create a list of newsletter thumbnails that will show and hide with an onclick event of it's parent header. The function is called properly to show the list, but won't hide it again on a second click. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing, but I am at a loss.

```js
function showBabList() {
  if (document.getElementById('bablist').style.display = "none") {
    document.getElementById('bablist').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('bablist').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 onclick="showBabList()">BITSandBYTES Newsletters</h2>
<div id="bablist" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <a href="newsletter/BITSandBYTES2017-07.pdf" target="bab"><img src="images/thumbs/BITSandBYTES2017-07_thumb.png" class="babthumb" height="100px" width="75px"></a>
    <a href="newsletter/BITSandBYTES2017-08.pdf" target="bab"><img src="images/thumbs/BITSandBYTES2017-08_thumb.png" class="babthumb" height="100px" width="75px"></a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you need to use == instead of = document.getElementById('bablist').style.display=="none"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function showBabList() {
  if (document.getElementById('bablist').style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById('bablist').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('bablist').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 onclick="showBabList()">BITSandBYTES Newsletters</h2>
<div id="bablist" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <a href="newsletter/BITSandBYTES2017-07.pdf" target="bab"><img src="images/thumbs/BITSandBYTES2017-07_thumb.png" class="babthumb" height="100px" width="75px"></a>
    <a href="newsletter/BITSandBYTES2017-08.pdf" target="bab"><img src="images/thumbs/BITSandBYTES2017-08_thumb.png" class="babthumb" height="100px" width="75px"></a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**WRONG**
`if (document.getElementById('bablist').style.display = "none")`

**CORRECT**
`if (document.getElementById('bablist').style.display == "none")`

Comment: BY GEORGE, you are correct. I assumed that since the function was called to begin with, it didn't have to resolve the statement further.